# Generic GDI+ error when trying to save image (on 64 Windows 7)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to save an image like this (from an asp.net mvc application):

```
public static void SaveJpeg(string path, Image img)
        {
            var qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, 100L);
            var jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg");

            var encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1);
            encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam;
            img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams);
        }
```

I gave full control permissions for the specific folder to the IIS_IUSRS, after tried using impersonation and gave permissions to the impersonated user, but still doesn't work.

all this helps on x86 Windows

anybody knows a fix ?

Comment: How does it not work, any error messages that you can paste here?

Comment: Does the exception get thrown on the `img.Save` line? It is usually because of permissions. Are you sure you have set the permissions right? Are you sure you application pool runs under the **IIS_IUSRS** user?

Comment: We need to know what the error is, and where it occurs in this code.

Comment: I think the actual error message is "A generic error occurred in GDI+". This is a very frequent error with GDI+, and a very annoying one because it gives so little detail...

Comment: @Omu, did you previously load the image from the same file?

Comment: Does Your pool run in IIS_IUSRS, do You impersonate anyone while saving the image? and more importadly HOW did YOu create the image? Was it created using Image.FromFile. If Yes probably the image is in use and You can't save it to the same location!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to create a file without using GDI, like this for example:

```
System.IO.File.CreateText("YourPath").WriteLine("Hello");
```

Then you will determine if you have write issues or not.

Note that in IIS, you have to enable write permissions on that folder not only in the file system, but also in the IIS manager.

If you in fact *can* write a file using `System.IO`, try to attach WinDbg to the process which will tell you more about the COM Error GDI+ is giving you.